# Can you not reference 2d array by a double pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I think my understanding of arrays and pointers is a little vague. The bigger goal is to swap pointers to two arrays. In the following example,  I first create a temporary pointer b that points to the static array a. Then i insert into a an element 1. I thought since b is pointing to a, b[0][0] would access the array but it gives me segmentation fault. Why is that so?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a[10][10];

    int ** b = (int **) a;

    a[0][0] = 1;

    cout << b[0][0] << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `int ** b = (int **) a;` to `int(*b)[10] = a;`, you will success.

You should know that the type of `a` is `int (*a)[10]`.